# Samba logging all Macs on our network to log.workstation

Tags: mac-osx, samba, netbios

We have a Samba share on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Per-machine logging is switched on via log.%m. I understand from the Samba documentation that %m is the NetBIOS machine name for the client machine.

Our network is a mixture of PCs and Macs. The PCs all run Windows 7, the Macs all run Yosemite. Each PC is being given it's own individual log file - log.david, log.andrew etc. All the Macs are being logged into the same file - log.workstation. However, all of these machines have their own NetBIOS names configured via System Preferences > Networking > Ethernet > Advanced > WINS - and all are connected to the correct workgroup. The name "workstation" doesn't appear anywhere on any of them.

So why isn't Samba seeing the configured name?

Comment: Did you also enter the `IP` address(es) of the `WINS` server(s)?

Comment: No - but then we haven't entered this on any of the Windows machines either, unless it's been picked up in DHCP somehow. We do have a Windows server on our network but it's not been set up as a WINS server - at least, not by me.

Comment: I've just checked the network settings on the Windows machines and none of them have a WINS server IP entered either.

Comment: The `IP` needs to be put in `System Preferences > Networking > Ethernet > Advanced > WINS` ... click the `+` and add it. See step #6 (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18500?locale=en_US)

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment we don't have a WINS server. I tried your advice anyway, just in case our Windows server had this enabled, and it didn't help. Still being logged to log.workstation.